# How to validate a uniqueness of an object in rails form apart from validating for exact string only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a **food_category model**. One of it's attribute is *title*. I used **validates_uniqueness_of :title** to validate uniqueness of title attribute. Here is the sample of the code:

```
  class FoodCategory < ApplicationRecord

     validates_uniqueness_of :title
```

Problem:

It validated the uniqueness for the repeated exact string only. If I enter the existing title again in small letter, the application allows to create the new object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `case_sensitive` option:

```
validates :title, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```